# Dynamic paging in antd

Tags: reactjs, pagination, antd

I want to use pagination component for a table in antd.
But my data is not fixed and I want the new page data to be taken from the backend with every click on the Next icon. However, I don't have the number of pages and I want the next button to stop working as soon as I receive empty data. How can I do this? It seems that in this component it is necessary to have a fixed and predetermined number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can give you some idea:
In Antd table you can set how many items the table will render before showing next button page (default 10).

So, supposing you already have the backend logic, what you can do is get first 10 itens from database and add an extra empty item in the array so antd table will render the next button.

When you click on it, table `onChange` event (take a look [here](https://ant.design/components/table#table)) will fire so now you can retrieve more data from your backend and append it to your array and again add an extra empty item at the end of array untill you recieve empty data from your server.

Hope I've helped you.